# Yeoman angular generator and bootstrap templates

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

So, I have an application that I have built using **yo angular** and all has been working for a while.
I have overridden some of the bootstrap templates (specifically the **datepicker**) and I have updated my grunt task to include these files when creating my templateCache:

```
ngtemplates: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            module: 'sapphire',
            htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
            usemin: 'scripts/scripts.js'
        },
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        src: [
            'app/**/*.html',
            'uib/**/*.html'
        ],
        dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js'
    }
},
```

The problem is when locally testing. It doesn't use the new template, which is annoying.
I have been using **injector** to inject my project files into my **index.html**, so I created this:

```
html: {
    options: {
        transform: function (filePath) {
            return '<script type="text/ng-template" src="\'' + filePath.replace('/src/', '') + '\'"></script>';
        }
    },
    files: {
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/uib/**/*.html'
        ]
    }
},
```

Which adds my templates to the bottom of the **index.html** like this:

```
<!-- injector:html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/datepicker/datepicker.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/datepicker/day.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/datepicker/month.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/datepicker/year.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/timepicker/timepicker.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-account-match.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-complaint.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-customer-services.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-match.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-order-match.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-product-match.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-stock-match.html'"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" src="'uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-user-match.html'"></script>
<!-- endinjector -->
```

These templates are put under the **JavaScript** files.
I have tried them above and still it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

Comment: When you say _"These templates are put under the JavaScript files"_ it's a bit unclear.... Does this mean that the `<script type="text/ng-template" ...>` tags   (i.e. those whose `src` paths are being changed via via the _injector_ task)  are put after the `<script type="text/javascript" ...>`  tags, which already exist in the target `.html`? If yes, are the `src` attributes for the `<script type="text/javascript" ...>` also being changed via another _injector_ task, or some other grunt task?

Comment: no, I mean it is put under the application script files, so under `<script src="app/app.js"></script>`